# How to check if a file is being read

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Could someone tell me whether it is possible to check if a file is being read. If it is being read then how do I make my program wait, till the reading is over so that it can begin writing into it.

I got the following error when I tried to write into a file that was being read:

```
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error trying to export to file : 
......(some errors not shown here) ....
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\servers_installs\tomcat6_9494\webapps\testdoc\logs\xyz.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:305)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Do you have control over both programs? If so, you could use a lockfile or other IPC to synchronize them. Otherwise, do as Dalal suggests below.

Comment: I have control only over write. I am writing into a pdf file. But, someone else is reading it. Dalal's solutions looks best. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @Harke, did the try-catch technique end up working for you?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Java in a while, but one option I believe you have is to use try catch blocks.  If an exception is caught, that means that writing failed, and you can keep trying again until it works.  Here's an example that may or may not be correct Java code.  But you should get the general idea.

```
boolean worked = false;
while (!worked && timeout<20)
{
   try
   {
     // writing code here

     // set worked to true
     worked = true;
   }
   catch
   {
     // do nothing
   }
}
```

Make sure this is running in a separate thread.  And also time it out in case there's another issue that's preventing the write from happening.  Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 - This is the correct methodology. Try doing what you want to do, and if there is an exception, deal with it (such as trying again, in this case).  If you put in special logic to check for the file being available, there will likely be race conditions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check if a file is being read:

1. Call the read function.
2. Call the write function.

Calling the functions in that order will automatically have the program FIRST read the file and then WRITE TO the file.

The following code may help:

```
try
{
    //enter the code which is giving the specified error here.
}
catch(JRException e)
{
      System.out.println("Jasper Exception.");
}
```

Make sure all your variables have been initialized correctly.
If you can post your code up here that would really help by the way.

Comment: I can only write into the pdf file. Someone else will be reading it, so I don't have control over it.

Comment: Now i see what you mean by "if a file is being read".  In that case you would have to check if a file is open or not; unfortunately i'm not familiar with how that works exactly, but i'm sure you can find an explanation by doing a few google searches.