# How to check whether the files is being used by another program

Tags: java

Is it possible in java to check whether a file is being used by another program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151716/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-being-read. Heres another SO question (It hasnt been answered but may lend a hand)

Answer (score 3):

If you have no control over the program that could potentially be using the file, then generally no.

If you do have control, then the program could tell you whether or not it's using the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file system is accessed by another Java program, then you can use in

```
java.nio.channels.FileLock
```

package, saying that its totally dependant on the OS.
See the link for further details.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows platforms a file is locked when it is opened.  So by testing (directly or indirectly) for a read or write lock, you can get a hint of whether some other process is reading or writing the file.  The problem is that most platforms *don't* lock open files by default, and on all platforms, files can be locked independently of reading and writing.  So this approach is going to be non-portable and unreliable, unless you have specific information about how "the other" application behaves.